# Continue log in when internet connection reestablished. Facebook SDK IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-3.1

I got an app that is connected to Facebook.

Upon start up of the app, if not logged out, the user will proceed to the home controller
, else he will stay in the login controller and asked to login.

The scenario:

1. User open the app with no internet connection.
2. The app will show an alertview saying that there is no connection.
3. The connection is established while the app is running.

The problem:

The problem is for user who have logged in and have an active FB session. The user is left hanging in the log in page even if the connection is established. He can only enter the home controller by logging out and logging in again or terminating the app.

What I want to accomplish:

I want that when the connection is established, the login will continue. When the FBToken is collected, my codes will automatically redirect the user to the home controller. How can I do that?

I want a simple code that will continue the interrupted login due to no internet connection.

At app delegate (these codes are responsible for checking if there is an active fb session):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"]
                                           allowLoginUI:YES
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                          // Handler for session state changes
                                          // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                          // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                          [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                      }];
    }

    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{


    // Note this handler block should be the exact same as the handler passed to any open calls.
    [FBSession.activeSession setStateChangeHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         // Retrieve the app delegate
         AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
         // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
         [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

}


- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error
{

    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){


        // Show the user the logged-in UI
        [self userLoggedIn];
        return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed

        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        [self userLoggedOut];
    }


    // Handle errors
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
        NSString *alertText;
        NSString *alertTitle;
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
            [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
        } else {

            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
            } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];

                // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
                // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
                // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            } else {
                //Get more error information from the error
                NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                // Show the user an error message
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
                [self showMessage:alertText withTitle:alertTitle];
            }
        }
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        [self userLoggedOut];
    }
}
```

Now, in the in the log in page:

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

//here is where is display modal the home view controller when the session token is successfully loaded

}
```

When there is no connection and the app failed to load the logged in user, the app is stuck in the log in viewcontroller. What code can I implement that when the connection goes back, the app will continue to log in (if a session is active).

Like:

```
if(connectionIsBack == Yes && session is active) {
      //relogin;
}
```

I already have the code to handle connection status changes (Reachability). Just need the code to relogin. I tried calling the codes from the app delegate but nothing happens.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the codes that you have used?

Comment: Sure, hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: did you manage to solve it?